# Reset ng-dirty status

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When I use `ng-model` like

```dart
<input type='text' maxlength='25' required ng-model='ctrl.inputValue'>
```

When I edit the text in the input element, the class `ng-dirty` is set, if I undo the change the class isn't changed back to `ng-pristine`.

Is there a way to make `ng-model` to reset the state to `ng-pristine` without reloading the view (beside directly modifying the `class` attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9s3T/) for an easy method.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.revertEdits = function() {
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
    };
}
```